# Making a calender in Access 2010

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a calender table that lists All dates in a certain range, and then some of the dates have other dates attatched to them for reference.

The table is 60_Days  and it has fields  Date and Date_60 with Date being the Actual calender and the Date_60 refers to other dates that need to be listed below Date.

I want to make a report that shows a normal calender but will display the Date_60 dates below Date where it exists. Any ideas? Visual Basic would be fine if it can be done. If I can export this into Excel and that somehow makes it easier, that is fine too. Thanks!!

Edit

I fail to see why this has been downvoted since no one seems to know my answer. Just being honest. I can't find what I am looking for and I have no idea where to start. I did read that for some reason, MS took out the Calender Control in forms and reports from Access in the 2010 version... Makes NO sense to me, but whatever. After doing more research, it seems like this MAY be able to be done in Excel, but I still don't see how it can be done yet.

Next Edit. The type of Calender I want to use should look somewhat like this

http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=880&tbm=isch&tbnid=WR_gZPF0plXvWM:&imgrefurl=http://www.docstoc.com/docs/16553160/Year-Round-School-Calendar-2009-2010-March-2010-S-7-14-21-28-7-14-21-28-S-M-1-8-15-22-29-T-2-9-16-23-30-W-3-10-17-24-31-T-4-11-18-25-F-5-12-19-26-S-6-13-20-27-W-4-11-18-25-T-5-12-19-26-F-6-13-20&docid=_aFOfbu3eBlxcM&imgurl=http://img.docstoccdn.com/thumb/orig/16553160.png&w=1275&h=1650&ei=Q8yKUJmuIZCK9gTd34HACg&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=357&sig=117327434000511743512&page=2&tbnh=150&tbnw=117&start=24&ndsp=35&ved=1t:429,r:5,s:20,i:158&tx=104&ty=49

Comment: I agree, with you. If they downvoted they should have atleast given an explanation why so that you could learn from anything you did wrong. the question seems fine to me.

Comment: I do admit that I am not the best at asking questions. I work really well in my head, but I don't always express it well enough. Thanks though.

Comment: does the answer I gave give you any idea of the kind of direction to move in now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can if using Access 2010 use the new table and store procedure trigger feature. You can thus write out the booking text to a table with 42 columns.

You then just bind the form to the table.

This is what I did to produce this example here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

In the above, I used the new web publishing feature of Access, so this runs in any browser including on my iPad.

However, if you have VBA, then just place 42 text boxes on the form, and use a query + loop to fill out the text boxes. You get something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't really understand how to do the VBA part or the thing with Triggers, but I think you set me on the right path. Do you have any idea how I would start this? I have some VBA experience, but it is quite limited. I also should add that I cannot see your picture for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you could just use Excel for this kind of thing. It seems simple enough. Here is a picture of one of the excel calendar templates, there are a bunch of these built in to excel:

[image: Calendar]

If, after you get a template like this set up, you want to put all the data from your date lists into this calendar you could write a simple looping macro. I'll provide some pseudo-code that you could use to help you with the logic.

---

Start by getting all the data for the lists into a sheet of the same workbook as your calendar.

Pseudo-code:

1. start a loop to loop through the list of dates
2. each time through the loop have the code:

   -Determine the month and select the correct sheet accordingly (a sheet for each month in template)
    -Determine the day and use the `Find` function to search for that day by `Value`
    -Paste the Date_60 values into the cell beneath that day (just like writing under a day on a normal calendar)

---

Also, here is a good link for coding with date data: http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: My next question would be, how do I get this all in one nice little calender? I think part of this is that I had to figure a lot of this stuff out on my own and my brain is partly fried and isn't working well. Haha. So would I need to code this by Visual Basic? I have some experience with it, but it has been a while. I Do have a nice long book on it though that I can reference.

Comment: @Chris This would be coded in VBA. Also, it depends on what you mean by a nice little calendar and what purpose it will be used for. to me this would be a nice little calendar, but with lots of dates listed under each date you may never achieve "nice little calendar" :p

Comment: @Chris another useful tool will be the record macro built-into Excel. This will help you not have to write as much code. once you get some code together you can post it back on here and I can help you get it working

Comment: Well, the person who created this calender before me actually calculated everything by hand and then typed it in Word. I will post a similar calender above.

Comment: you could make a calendar with just small numbers like those you showed in the picture above and when you click on a day just have a messagebox pop up with the other dates for that day listed in it. Either that or you could have an actual form pop up with a text box kind of thing.

Comment: Well I need this to basically show it because this needs to be printed out.

Comment: why couldn't you use my first method then? because how will you show a list of dates under a calendar that small?

Comment: My guess is that if someone could type them small enough to be seen in word, I could do this some other way without having to manually type in each date.